# UILabel inside UITableViewCell - height isn't adjusting correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, height

Check out the second `UILabel` inside of the pink `UITableViewCell.` As you can see, the text inside it is cut-off. I've been trying to get the height of this `UILabel` to correctly expand or shrink as a function of how much text is plugged into it - and its not working.

[image]

• I'm using `AutoLayouts`
• The `UILabel` is pinned on all 4 sides to the `ContentView` - which of course is inside the `UITableViewCell`
• The Cells are all `Static` cells by the way, not `Prototype` cells.
• Here's the code I'm using:

(in viewWillAppear)

```
descriptionLabel.text = " < a bunch of text goes here > "
descriptionLabelSize = descriptionLabel.sizeThatFits(descriptionLabel.bounds.size)
// here's a global var I use to store the height:
descriptionLabelHeight = descriptionLabelSize.height
```

then, in viewDidAppear (and FYI, I also tried putting the following in `will` and `didLayoutSubviews` and in all sorts of other permutations:)

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    var newFrame = descriptionLabel.frame
    newFrame.size.height = descriptionLabelHeight
    descriptionLabel.frame = newFrame

    descriptionLabel.setNeedsLayout()
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Finally, in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` I use the global var to adjust the TableViewCell's height:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: return 50
    case 1: return descriptionLabelHeight+20   // the + 20 is for padding & margin
    default: return 50
    }
}
```

The result is mixed: the height of the Label - and the Cell housing it - ***does*** adjust - but not enough. It always ends up being too short. And I don't mean that it just cuts off a couple of words, its ***way*** too short, cutting off multiple sentences. 
But again: the height ***does*** adjust. And that's the weird part. Its working - just not enough.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell table view to dynamically scale the cells based on content:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Then, you can remove your implementation of `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` - cells should scale automatically. Remember to setup layout constraints correctly though. Without it dynamic sizing won't work.

Comment: Well I already tried `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and it didn't work. But let me be specific: in `viewDidLoad` I put `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, then I commented out `heightForRowAtIndexPath` - and all the cells came back the same height (44 points.) Should I have done that differently?

Comment: By the way, can you be more specific re "Remember to setup layout constraints correctly"? I described in my Q how the Label is set up: its pinned to the ContentView on all 4 sides. Is that not correct? If so, what would be the correct constraints set up for the Label - or other elements that may be involved in the equation?